# Вывод ascii кода символа

Tags: ассемблер

Например есть строка "Hello". как вывести ascii код каждного символа?

Comment: Написать процедуру вывода кода одного символа, и в цикле передать ей по одному все символы.

Comment: @Akina как вывести код символа?

Comment: Коды в какой системе счисления выводить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, раскопал-таки в архивах

```
; Turbo Assembler    Copyright (c) 1988, 1991 By Borland International, Inc.
; HEX.ASM
; From the Turbo Assembler Users Guide

CODE      SEGMENT
          ASSUME cs:CODE,ds:NOTHING

; Parameters (+2 because of push bp)

byteCount EQU BYTE PTR  ss:[bp+6]
num       EQU DWORD PTR ss:[bp+8]

; Function result address (+2 because of push bp)

resultPtr EQU DWORD PTR ss:[bp+12]

HexStr    PROC FAR
          PUBLIC HexStr

          push bp
          mov bp,sp          ;get pointer into stack
          les di,resultPtr   ;get address of function result
          mov dx,ds          ;save Turbo's DS in DX
          lds si,num         ;get number address
          mov al,byteCount   ;how many bytes?
          xor ah,ah          ;make a word
          mov cx,ax          ;keep track of bytes in CX
          add si,ax          ;start from MS byte of number
          dec si
          shl ax,1           ;how many digits? (2/byte)
          cld                ;store # digits (going forward)
          stosb              ;in destination string's length byte
HexLoop:
          std                ;scan number from MSB to LSB
          lodsb              ;get next byte
          mov ah,al          ;save it
          shr al,1           ;extract high nibble
          shr al,1
          shr al,1
          shr al,1
          add al,90h         ;special hex conversion sequence
          daa                ;using ADDs and DAA's
          adc al,40h
          daa                ;nibble now converted to ASCII
          cld                ;store ASCII going up
          stosb
          mov al,ah          ;repeat conversion for low nibble
          and al,0Fh
          add al,90h
          daa
          adc al,40h
          daa
          stosb
          loop HexLoop       ;keep going until done
          mov ds,dx          ;restore Turbo's DS
          pop bp
          ret 6              ;parameters take 6 bytes
HexStr    ENDP
CODE      ENDS
          END
```

Comment: Сложно очень. Можно же упростить раза в два так.

Comment: Можно, кто бы спорил. Но это цитата, а их не корректируют.

Comment: Осталось понять как вам по вопросу удалось догадаться, что требуются 16ричные коды и что ассемблер для платформы x86

Comment: Наванговал. Из самого вопроса больше не выжимается, и автор не спешит уточниться. Впрочем, если я ошибаюсь, обидно мне не будет.

Comment: @Mike какой алгоритм перевода например 'А' в hex 61?

Comment: @YuriPopiv 61 это вообще то маленькая буква 'a', вам надо регистр буквы поменять ? И собственно приведенная тут процедура  рабочая, отлично переведет.